# For some reason this never exits the for loop to print out the final value

Tags: c++, loops, arduino

So basically the following code never exits the for loop, and I need it to exit the for loop in order to print whatever the buffer finally contains once it's looped through each char.
However, as I previously stated, the loop (to my knowledge) just keeps on going and doesn't end, hence why buffer is never printed OUTSIDE the loop (I am aware it print's repeatedly inside the loop).
I'm fairly certain and if statement with a break command would do the trick here however after staring at it for a while I still can't figure out what it would be.

Another note is that the code cannot be inside the `void loop()` function and must be inside the `void setup()` function

This is the code

```
char iValue;
const int bufflen = 10;
char buffer[bufflen];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println(buffer);
  int index = 0;
  int i = 0;

  for(i=0;i<bufflen;i++) {

      while (!Serial.available()) {
          ;
      }
      iValue = Serial.read();
      buffer[index] = iValue;
      //Serial.println(buffer);
      //Serial.println(iValue);
      Serial.println(buffer);
      index++;
      if (index > bufflen){
          break;
      }
  }

  Serial.println(buffer);
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: This is not a `c` question. removing tag. also, please indent your code properly.

Comment: Your while loop will probably cause this problem.

Comment: Is there anything that can cause Serial.available() to become false?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that while (!Serial.available()) loop causes the hang? If the serial object is not filled  in another thread, then once the while loop is entered, it would block any ability to read further data?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the condition `while(Serial.available()) { //do something }``

This way, the main `loop()` function will continue to run and the `while` loop will only be executed when the condition is met, i.e. when there are serial data available to read.

The `Serial.available()` function is a callback to another function run outside of `void loop()`

This is what a real Arduino program looks like:

```
int main(void)
{
 init();
 initVariant();
#if defined(USBCON)
 USBDevice.attach();
#endif

 setup();

 for (;;) {
  loop();
  if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
 }

 return 0;
}
```

As you can see, if your program is stuck in `while(!Serial.avalaible())` inside loop, there is no way it could reach the 'if (serialEventRun) serialEventrun();` line. Therefore the issue you are having.

Here is a very interesting discussion about this issue on the Arduino Google Groups : [Defect In SerialEvent](https://groups.google.com/a/arduino.cc/forum/#!topic/developers/dtxWeWVza5s)

Hope this helps.